# How to display all the vendors of selected product in sale order lines in odoo 15

Tags: python, xml, odoo-14, odoo-15

**i want to display all the vendors of product when i select one in sales order lines**

i tried this code

```
vendors = fields.Many2one(related='product_id.seller_ids_name')
```

it works but not as expected

as you see in the image i get only one vendor of the selected product, what i want is display all the vendors of that product (product A) not only one

[image]

Can you help me with that ?

**thanks**

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a **Many2many** field if you want to show multiple vendors in sale order line.

vendor_ids = fields.Many2many(comodel_name_of_vendor_model, string='Vendors', related='source_field.related_value')

Please make sure that your source field is also a Many2many field.

Comment: im sorry i dont know how to implement that